# Kiu estu la signifo de "pardonon"?

Tags: word-meaning

Mi aŭdis homojn diri *Pardonu min*, *Pardonu* aŭ *Pardonon* kiam ili celas la saman aferon. Sed pri la lasta mi pensis: Se *Dankon* esprimas "Mi donas al vi dankon", ĉu *Pardonon* ne estas "Mi donas al vi pardonon"? Tiukaze ĝi devus esti dirata kiel respondo alternative al "Mi pardonas vin".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La kompleta frazo estas: *Mi petas pardonon.*